# Variable interpolation issue in finding users in MS Graph API v1.0

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, interpolation

I am using below code to search user details:

```
 var users2 = await graphServiceClient.Users.
   .Request()
   .Filter("startswith(displayName,'Robert')")
   .Select(u => new {
       u.DisplayName,
       u.MobilePhone,
       u.UserPrincipalName
   }).GetAsync();
```

and it works, but when i use below code and try to store the user display name in a string and then run the query it returns null.

```
 string dispName = mem.DisplayName;

    var users2 = await graphServiceClient.Users
   .Request()
   .Filter("startswith(displayName,'{dispName}')")
   .Select(u => new {
       u.DisplayName,
       u.MobilePhone,
       u.UserPrincipalName
   })
   .GetAsync();
```

I tried with $'{dispName}' also ,it doesn't work.
Please help.

Comment: You haven't interpolated anything - interpolated strings start with a $ - `$"startswith(displayName, '{dispName}')"` - see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated - not the variable itself, the whole string.

Comment: @Charleh Yes, it works . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its should be like this as per [$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
    string dispName = mem.DisplayName;

    var users2 = await graphServiceClient.Users
   .Request()
   .Filter($"startswith(displayName,'{dispName}')")
   .Select(u => new {
       u.DisplayName,
       u.MobilePhone,
       u.UserPrincipalName
   })
   .GetAsync();
```

Please refer [$filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) to know more about [filter parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter).