# GraphServiceClient filter issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I followed this page to setup a MicrosoftGraphProvider: http://www.keithmsmith.com/get-started-microsoft-graph-api-calls-net-core-3/

This is working correctly, as I am able to get a list of all of my users with the following request.

```
var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

However, I don't always want all of the users returned, so I have a filter on a user by email.

The example says to do this

```
var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users[email].Request().GetAsync();
```

But this always results in user not found, even if I pass a valid email from the response of all users.

So I tried to build a filter, and do it this way.

```
var test = await _graphServiceClient.Users["$filter=startswith(mail,'test@email.com')"].Request().GetAsync();

var test = await _graphServiceClient.Users["$filter=(startswith(mail,'test@email.com'))"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Both of these returned the error:

```
Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
Message: The $filter path segment must be in the form $filter(expression), where the expression resolves to a boolean.
```

This filter works fine when I use it in Postman calling the url directly. But I am trying to use their sdk and it is not working as expected.

What is wrong with this filter query?

Comment: You could have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459481/variable-interpolation-issue-in-finding-users-in-ms-graph-api-v1-0/60462549#60462549)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$filter` should be specified in `Filter` method. The article you followed does not reflect the current API.

```
var users = await _graphServiceClient.Users
.Request()
.Filter("startswith(mail,'test@email.com')")
.GetAsync();
```

Check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: From what I can see this way retrieves all the users and then do the filtering. On a large active directory this is not a good solutiong

Comment: @Morten I think that filtering is applied on the server side and Graph API returns filtered results. How did you find out that it retrieves all users? I will look on it.

Comment: @Morten I guess that you have different problem, so it's better to create a new question for it and describe steps how to reproduce the issue. This answer is related to question where the filter was used in wrong way.